# Cutting image within an image with Corona SDK

Tags: iphone, coronasdk

I was wondering if it's possible to cut an image within an image with the Corona SDK using your finger? If it is indeed possible, I'd like to know how. It's for an iphone game. Thanks.

Comment: If it's useful for you , I've find this resource here : http://springboardpillow.blogspot.it/2014/03/polygon-slicing-with-corona-sdk.html it's not mine, you must contact the developer I think, bye

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this.
One is to replace the image with two halves of the original.
You will need to edit the image, which is cumbersome.

Second is to use bitmap masks as alpha masks.
The masks are grayscale images: **white = show, black = hide**.
This method won't require you to change the image.

Create two halves of the original image.
Hide half of each image shown here as **A** & **B**
using **2** separate alpha masks.

[image: sliced image masks]

Sample Code from Corona [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/sample-code/x-ray)

This would assume your image would always be sliced in the same way.

Comment: Thanks but I want to be able to draw the shape with my fingers. Is that actually possible?

Comment: @Jehan with the latest Corona build, no. Not that I know of.

Comment: Alright. I figured I won't be doing that after all. Instead, I'll use the sample x-ray code you posted. However, I was wondering if it's possible to save the masked image as a jpeg.